# Is coupled pairs an appropriate phrase?

Tags: terminology

Is coupled pairs an appropriate phrase, please?

> The data are *coupled pairs* of wavelength and intensity

I mean points (\lambda, I).

Comment: The sentence is grammatical; whether what you call a "coupled pair" is **actually** called a coupled pair is something which is more likely to be on-topic in [physics.se] given that it's part of a specialised terminology. However [their help pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) don't mention terminology as being on-topic there. I'm not convinced this question is on-topic here.

Comment: I thought of ***paired values***, but then I found this - [***Bivariate data** are paired values of data from two quantitative variables.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22data+are+paired+values%22)

Comment: *Coupled pairs* is redundant, so there may be some confusion about whether you are talking about 2 values or 4 values.

Comment: Thank you very much; thus, 'paired values' are the appropriate words?

Comment: What's wrong with *ordered pairs*, which is the standard term in mathematics?

Comment: Perhaps with the actual graphical representation in the question (image or table), it would be easier to provide a suggestion. "Key–value pair" is a common term in computer science (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair), but I'm not sure if it applies to this context.

Comment: OK, thank you very much

Comment: Without knowing the intent of the phrase, we can't tell whether any suggestion is appropriate.

Comment: The intend is to say what one point in the graph means. Thus, I can call it ordered pairs as follow from the advice above

Comment: The question is reasonable for this site because it relates to the meanings that may be attached to "couple". It would have been helpful to all commentators if you gave us a little more of your own research on the matter or more about the context of the question.

Comment: The term *coupled-pairs* is a prime example of overcorrection. Both *couple* and *pair* refer to two objects, or instances of something. It's not ungrammatical, but it's certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *coupled pair* applies to a pair of two objects that have the property of exerting forces on each other and are therefore capable of exchanging energy with each other. I suggest the Earth and Moon as an example of a coupled pair because they are connected by the gravitational force.

Wikipedia has a handy and more general account:

> Two objects are said to be coupled when they are interacting with each other. In classical mechanics, coupling is a connection between two oscillating systems, such as pendulums connected by a spring. The connection affects the oscillatory pattern of both objects. In particle physics, two particles are coupled if they are connected by one of the four fundamental forces (gravitational, electromagnetic, strong and weak interactions).
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction)

The term is therefore in necessary and acceptable use in physics and physical chemistry.

It is hard to see how extension of meaning to a pair comprising *wavelength* and *intensity* is justified, because these are two characteristics of electromagnetic radiation that cannot exchange energy with each other, there being no force between them, so they cannot be coupled.

The terms suggested by other commentators are therefore more appropriate in this context. Use *ordered pairs* or *paired values*.